# Issue with creating links to items in Joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, article

I am trying to use *Joomla 3.0* on a *GoDaddy* hosting server. After installation, the administrator panel works fine and I am able to add new articles, create new menus, etc.

The problem is that when I add a new link (e.g. via creating a new article and linking it to the menu item), then on clicking this new menu item, I get the following error:

> ```
> The requested page cannot be found.
> An error has occurred while processing your request.
> You may not be able to visit this page because of:
>
>     an out-of-date bookmark/favourite
>     a mistyped address
>     a search engine that has an out-of-date listing for this site
>     you have no access to this page
>
> Go to the Home Page
> Home Page
> If difficulties persist, please contact the System Administrator of this site and report the error below.   
> 404 Category not found 
> Back to Top
> ```

This happens for all new links that I create. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is "Use URL rewriting" enabled in Global Configuraton?

If so, try copying htaccess.txt to .htaccess in the root folder of your website.